# Как правильно написать слово

Tags: орфография

Как вариант написания верый:лосиха или лосица?

Comment: Интересно! Впервые в жизни вижу вариант "*лосица*"!

Answer (score 4):

Из словаря Ушакова: ЛОСИХА и (обл.) ЛОСИЦА, самка лося.

Таким образом, лосиха - это общепринятое название, а лосица дается с пометкой "областное".

Для справок

ДИАЛЕКТ (от греч. dialektos – говор, наречие).

Разновидность общенародного языка, определяемая ограниченным числом людей, связанных территориальной (ТЕРРИТОРИАЛЬНЫЙ ДИАЛЕКТ), социальной (социальный диалект), профессиональной (профессиональный диалект) общностью. Изучается в рамках стилистики современного литературного языка.